# Adding new cart block within local.xml - magento

Tags: magento, layout

Trying to add a new cart block to the header within local.xml this is what i have

```
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_topbar" as="topCart" template="checkout/cart/top-cart.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Then with in the header i call it with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCart')?>` however it shows nothing.

If i try changing the type to `type="core/template"` then the template will show the content. So this leads me to think i'm missing something specific to the `checkout/cart_sidebar` type?

The `top-cart.phtml` file simple contains a single text line to eliminate anything within that.

Comment: You've taken all of the proper diagnostic steps, very good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's is your local.xml?

syntax is correct.

have you modify any thing else in Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php?

Comment: I haven't, but previous developers might have. At least i know the syntax is all good and in theory it should work. Thxs for the help

Comment: Incase anyone else is wondering, turned out to be a bigger issue with the cart in general from previous devs. The syntax and placements are all good from the question.

Comment: can you send me Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php this file please. please check in local first. and mention in comment that file is collected from local/core